# filter and sort subdocuments by Date with Mongo / Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Mongoose model like the one below. I'd like to have some subdocuments ordered, and filtered by date (ex. only the last 10 subdocs)

A TotalPlafond has a number (`tot_plafond`), and a list of sub Plafonds for each debtor. `tot_plafond` is updated calculating the list of `debtor_plafond`, which is calculated summing all the transfers.
When I ask the TotalPlafond, I'd like to have only the last 10 transfers, so I should order transfers by date, and take just the last 10. 
I could also have the need to have just some transfers between 2 dates.

How could I do this with Mongoose?

This obviously doesn't work.

```
// this just orders resulting docs, not subdocs
TotalPlafond.findById(id)
            .sort('debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks.transfers.date')
```

Here you are my model:

```
/* ====  TotalPlafond Mongoose Model ==== */
{
 tot_plafond     : {type : Number},
 debtor_plafonds : [
    {
       debtor_id      : {type: ObjectID},
       debtor_plafond : {type : Number},
       debtor_taks: [
          {
            task_id   : {type : ObjectID},
            transfers : [ 
                         {
                          amount : {type : Number},
                          date   : {type : Date}
                         }
                        ]
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
}
```

I want to take one TotalPlafond (ex. `TotalPlafond.findById(id)`), with all the debtor_plafond, but with just last 10 transfers of each debtor_task of each debtor_plafond

Comment: I am not clear about transfers array as it must be an array of object with keys "amount" and "date".

Comment: sorry, a parenthesis were missing. Now it's fixed

Comment: Do you want to fetch last 10 "transfers" for each "debtor_plafonds"?

Comment: Could you please add sample doc and your desired result if possible. It would be helpful to write a query.

Comment: yes, I want to take one TotalPlafond (ex. `TotalPlafond.findById(id)`), with all the debtor_plafond, but with just last 10 transfers of each debtor_task of each debtor_plafond

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398")
        }        
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$debtor_plafonds"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks.transfers"
    },
    {
        $sort: { 
            "debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks.transfers.date": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "_id": "$_id",  
                "tot_plafond": "$tot_plafond",  
                "debtor_plafonds": "$debtor_plafonds.debtor_id",
                "debtor_taks": "$debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks.task_id",
            },
            // data : { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            transfers : { 
                $push: { 
                    "amount": "$debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks.transfers.amount",
                    "date": "$debtor_plafonds.debtor_taks.transfers.date"    
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            tot_plafond: "$_id.tot_plafond",
            debtor_plafonds: "$_id.debtor_plafonds",
            debtor_taks: "$_id.debtor_taks",
            transfers: { $slice : [ "$transfers",2 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

I tried it will dummy data. You will get the result as below:

```
/* 1 createdAt:23/05/2019, 14:42:54*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398"),
    "tot_plafond" : 20,
    "debtor_plafonds" : ObjectId("5c8d5cd4d8d2ab15b37c780a"),
    "debtor_taks" : ObjectId("5cad84b93d124a151f633af1"),
    "transfers" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:23/05/2019, 14:42:54*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398"),
    "tot_plafond" : 20,
    "debtor_plafonds" : ObjectId("5c8d5cd4d8d2ab15b37c780a"),
    "debtor_taks" : ObjectId("5c91c0f121a78f19d9eb3531"),
    "transfers" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 createdAt:23/05/2019, 14:42:54*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398"),
    "tot_plafond" : 20,
    "debtor_plafonds" : ObjectId("5ca449f6b3171315a29a90dc"),
    "debtor_taks" : ObjectId("5ca449f6b3171315a29a90db"),
    "transfers" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-20T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-19T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 4 createdAt:23/05/2019, 14:42:54*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398"),
    "tot_plafond" : 20,
    "debtor_plafonds" : ObjectId("5cad84b93d124a151f633af0"),
    "debtor_taks" : ObjectId("5cad84b93d124a151f633af2"),
    "transfers" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 5 createdAt:23/05/2019, 14:42:54*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398"),
    "tot_plafond" : 20,
    "debtor_plafonds" : ObjectId("5ca449f6b3171315a29a90dc"),
    "debtor_taks" : ObjectId("5cad84b93d124a151f633af3"),
    "transfers" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 6 createdAt:23/05/2019, 14:42:54*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce66416ff87476e5eef0398"),
    "tot_plafond" : 20,
    "debtor_plafonds" : ObjectId("5cad84b93d124a151f633af0"),
    "debtor_taks" : ObjectId("5c91c0f121a78f19d9eb3532"),
    "transfers" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T10:32:00.313+05:30")
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know you're desired result and i will modify the query for that.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I'm testing it out. Anyway it's just for the sort right? there is no "filter", for instance, the last 10 transfers, or all the transfers between 2 dates

Comment: Actually, I could delegate the sort process to the client, avoiding to overload the server. But the query should filter just the transfers I need (last 10 days or between 2 dates)